# In JavaScript, what is the difference between a property name in double-quotes ("") and without?

Tags: javascript, object, properties

```
var car = { manyCars: {a: "Saab", "b": "Jeep"}, 7: "Mazda" };
```

What's the difference between `car.manyCars.a` and `car.manyCars.b` in this example?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

None whatsoever.

Quotes allow you to specify names which are not valid javascript identifiers, but both `a` and `b` are. For example, this wouldn't be legal:

```
var car = { a*b: "Saab" };
```

whereas this would be

```
var car = { "a*b": "Saab" };
```

As a*b is not a valid identifier.

Note that JSON (which is based on JavaScript) does not allow unquoted names.

**Edit**
An exception here, as you've noticed, you can use numbers without quoting them, which are not valid javascript identifiers. This is actually rather weird, don't have a good reason for this, probably the opportunity to shorthand the declaration. `car.7` won't parse for the same reason, it is not a valid identifier, and you need to use `car[7]`.

Comment: Thanks. So as a rule of thumb you should always use them?

Comment: Also, when calling the property '7', why is car[7] used rather than car.7 (in the tutorial)? Or can you use either?

Comment: @DarkLightA; It depends a little on context, if you intend to use your objects as traditional objects, I prefer not to use quotes (as you do want to access them using the '.'-operator). If instead, you're using it as a general purpose associative array, I'd use quotes, and access the elements with the '[]' operator.

Comment: @DarkLightA the dot and subscript (['']) are interchangable, however subscript lets you use an expression as a key - for example, `someobj[x-1]`.

Answer (score 1):

As roe said, there's no difference in the end, but it allows to you to use otherwise reserved keywords or invalid identifiers:

```
var x = { 'a b c' : 1, 'a%#!6!#' : 1};
```

It probably isn't a bad idea to always use quotes. Different javascript engines consider different things to be reserved. For example, this works fine in a browser, but causes a syntax error in Rhino:

```
var x = { native : true };
```

The Mozilla Developer Network has some good information too: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Member_Operators

**Dot notation**

> `some_object.property`
>
> `property` must be a valid JavaScript identifier, i.e. a sequence of alphanumerical characters, also including the underscore ("_") and dollar sign ("$"), that cannot start with a number. For example, object.$1 is valid, while object.1 is not.

**Bracket notation**

> `some_object[property]`
>
> `property` is a string. The string does not have to be a valid identifier; it can have any value, e.g. "1foo", "!bar!", or even " " (a space).

Comment: good point on the reserved words, although it you might not want to use those as names anyway, as `x.for` wouldn't work (at least I think it doesn't, does it?)

Comment: It does work: `x['for']`

Comment: Actually, that was a bad example. This works for me: `x = { for : 1}; alert(x.for);`

Comment: @M28; I said, `x.for`, not `x['for']` (which of course works, just as `var f="for"; x[f]`). @nickf, that's very interesting. I'm not so sure that's legal though, isn't `for` a reserved word? Might mess up in some parsers.

Comment: Well, my solution is granted to work on any javascript parser, for can be a keyword on some parser.

Comment: @M28; while correct, your 'solution' has very little to do with the problem at hand in this case, as we're talking specifically about *unquoted* property names.