# Is there any functional difference between using and not using quotes with javascript property name assignments?

Tags: javascript, variable-assignment

I'm not sure of the exact wording to use, but I have seen object assignments in javascript done two wasy

```
$('#test').dataTable({ fnInitComplete: myFunction });
```

and

```
$('#test').dataTable({ "fnInitComplete": myFunction });
```

Is there any actual difference between these, or any gotchas to be aware of?

Comment: possible duplicate of [In JavaScript, what is the difference between a property name in double-quotes ("") and without?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4534404/in-javascript-what-is-the-difference-between-a-property-name-in-double-quotes) and [Single quotes in JavaScript object literal](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2788236/single-quotes-in-javascript-object-literal) and [JSON syntax for property names](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/380855/json-syntax-for-property-names)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is no difference.

However, if the key is not a valid identifier (eg, it's a keyword, or it has spaces or punctuation), quotes are required.

Also, the [JSON standard](http://json.org) (which is not Javascript) always requires double-quotes.

Comment: +1: Good to know. I was wondering the same thing myself. Does this apply across the board with jQuery?

Comment: @JamesJohnson: This is Javascript syntax.  It has nothing to do with jQuery.

Comment: get used to Double quotes. As @SLaks says, the JSON standard is double quotes. When handling JSON on the server (with Java or whatever), most libraries that parse JSON for you are going to want to see double quotes. So, just because Javascript JSON doesn't care, other JSON engines will.

Comment: I was wondering speficially about using JSON to set properties using jQuery, like when adding attributes for example.

Comment: @JamesJohnson: That's still Javascript syntax.  However, **strings** passed to `$.parseJSON` must be valid JSON.

Comment: @aaronfrost: There is nothing such as "JavaScript JSON". JavaScript object literal syntax and JSON are not the same.

Answer (score 2):

The [currently accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7986200/96656) is incorrect:

> However, if the key is not a valid identifier (eg, it's a keyword, or it has spaces or punctuation), quotes are required.

The quotes aren’t required if you use a numeric literal as a property name. Also, keywords and reserved words are valid identifier names, and all identifier names (not just [identifiers](http://mathiasbynens.be/notes/javascript-identifiers)) are valid JavaScript property names.

From [***Unquoted property names / object keys in JavaScript***](http://mathiasbynens.be/notes/javascript-properties), my write-up on the subject:

> Quotes can only be omitted if the property name is a numeric literal or [a valid identifier name](http://mathiasbynens.be/notes/javascript-identifiers).
>
> […]
>
> Bracket notation can safely be used for all property names.
>
> […]
>
> Dot notation can *only* be used when the property name is a valid identifier name.

I also made a tool that will tell you if any given property name can be used without quotes and/or with dot notation. Try it at [mothereff.in/js-properties](http://mothereff.in/js-properties).

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

The main difference is that with quotes, you can use keys with spaces, js keywords, etc that are illegal as normal symbols.  That's why JSON requires them.

Comment: Umm, what does the J stand for?  Regardless, I never implied it was, but it IS a subset of javascript, and the fact that you can, for instance, paste JSON into a js file and have it work is one of the benefits of JSON.  The fact that you have to make sure keys are quoted if you go the other direction is a caveat, and possibly a reason to standardize on using quotes for keys on your object literals.  Anyway, the JSON comment was an aside, relevant to some I'd think.

Comment: Ok, I just was confused that you brought JSON in (and made this conclusion).

Answer (score 0):

Without the quotes, the property name must be either a number, or a valid JavaScript identifier. With the quotes, you can use an arbitrary string. Quoting a string that's already a valid JS identifier is functionally identical to using just the identifier.